# CanJS add custom MODEL method

Tags: javascript, rest, javascriptmvc, canjs, canjs-model

I want to add another function to get result from a CanJs Model

i Have something like this:

```
   VideomakerModel = can.Model({
        id:'ID',
        findAll: 'GET /videomakers/',
        findNear:  function( params ){
                         return $.post("/get_near_videomakers/",
                         {address:params.address},
                         undefined ,"json")
                    }
         },{});

    VideomakerModel.findNear({address : "Milan"}, function(videomakers) {
                var myList = new VideomakerControl($('#accordionVm'), {
                videomakers : videomakers,
                view: 'videomakersList'
            });
        });
```

If I name the method findAll it works correctly,
otherwise naming it findNear it never reach the callback

should I extend MODEL is some way?? is there a way of add a function like FindAll?

thank you very much

Comment: Up voting to offset the down vote. No reason for the down vote was given and this is a legitimate question.

Answer (score 2):

CanJS only adds the conversion into a Model instance for the standard `findOne`, `findAll` etc. Model methods. You will have to do that yourself in your additional implementation by running the result through `VideoMaker.model` (for a single item) or `VideoMaker.models` (for multiple items):

```
VideomakerModel = can.Model({
  id:'ID',
  findAll: 'GET /videomakers/',
  findNear:  function( params ) {
    var self = this;
    return $.post("/get_near_videomakers/", {
      address:params.address
    }, undefined ,"json").then(function(data) {
      return self.model(data);
    });
  }
 },{});
```

Comment: Hello Daff,
when i call the function with:

`VideomakerModel.findNear({address : address}, function(videomakers) {
                      videomakerControl = new VideomakerControl($('#accordionVm'), {
                          videomakers : videomakers,
                          view: 'videomakersList'
                      });
`
the data are ok, but it never fires the callback,
any idea why?
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, it is necessary to do so:

```
 VideomakerModel = can.Model({
       id:'ID',
       findAll: 'GET /videomakers/'
    }, 
    {
       findNear: function(options, success){
           can.ajax({
                url: "/get_near_videomakers/",
                type: 'POST',
                data: options,
                success: success
            })
       }  
    })

var myList = new VideomakerControl({});

myList.findNear({address:params.address}, function(resulrRequest){
    //success
} )
```